# Socket server crashes while client has disconnected

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, send, dump

Practicing C language and socket programming.

Server code crashes when it checks live clients and a client has disconnected (e.g. connection dropped). I am not experienced reading a GDB dump. Can someone point out what I am missing here?

Here is the server code. The client connects and disconnects. The server checks for disconnected client(s) by sending a small message and waiting for a reply. After getting a broken pipe error, the code crashes.

```c
void * client_hartbeat()
{
    int ret = 0, i;
    char send_msg[50] = "e";
    char recv_msg[50];
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(3);
        printf("\nchecking for disconnected clients\n");
        memset(&recv_msg,0,sizeof(recv_msg));
        for(i=0;i<CLIENTS;i++){
            if(client_pool[i]!=0){
                printf("TEST0, socket: %i thread: %i\n", client_pool[i],pthread_self());
                if(send(client_pool[i],send_msg,sizeof(send_msg),0) < 0){
                    printf("send error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                }else if(recv(client_pool[i],recv_msg,sizeof(recv_msg),0) < 0){
                    printf("receive error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                }
                printf("TEST1, socket: %i thread: %d\n", client_pool[i],pthread_self());
            }
        }
    }
    printf("TEST1\n");
    pthread_exit(&th2);
}
```

Here is the GDB dump:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
waiting connections...
[New Thread 0x7ffff7dba640 (LWP 22567)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff75b9640 (LWP 22568)]

checking for disconnected clients

checking for disconnected clients
TEST0, socket: 4 thread: -144992704
TEST1, socket: 4 thread: -144992704

checking for disconnected clients
TEST0, socket: 4 thread: -144992704
TEST1, socket: 4 thread: -144992704

checking for disconnected clients
TEST0, socket: 4 thread: -144992704

Thread 3 "a.out" received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff75b9640 (LWP 22568)]
__libc_send (flags=<optimized out>, len=50, buf=0x7ffff75b8e10, fd=4) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/send.c:28
28      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/send.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

Comment: You should probably ignore that signal. `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`. Unrelated: You send `sizeof(send_msg)` (50 bytes) even though I suspect that you only one to send 1 byte (the `e`).

Comment: I did try with 1 byte earlier also tried strlen(send_msg) instead sizeof(send_msg) and still code crashes

Comment: Yes, that was an unrelated comment. Did you try to ignore the signal? You could also use the flag `MSG_NOSIGNAL` in your `send` and `recv` calls to not generate the signal if you try to `send`/`recv` on a closed socket.

Comment: I wrote an answer with my suggestions instead

Comment: Good idea and just tried using MSG_NOSIGNAL now server code is not crashing and from server point off view client is still connected, that unfortunately is not solving this issue. Server should know that client has disconnected.

Comment: The server-side `send` will return `-1` if the client has closed the connection and `errno` will be set to `EPIPE` (Broken pipe). Are you saying that the `send` succeeds?

Comment: When I use MSG_NOSIGNAL flag, send returns 0 and from server side client is connected. Without flag I get broken pipe what is true. Problem is that after server gets broken pipe server code crashes.

Comment: Ok, `0` was surprising, but it's still an indication that something went wrong since you are trying to send at least `1` byte. Set `errno = 0;` before the `send` and check `errno` after the `send`, even if it returns `0`. Is it set to `EPIPE`?

Comment: After reading more about it I made a small program to test it. I added a working solution to the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*Are you saying that the send succeeds?*" - that is a possibility, yes. Until the OS *knows* that the connection is actually gone (either by a `FIN`, or a keep-alive timeout, etc), it will happily accept `send()` requests until the socket's internal buffer fills up.

Comment: @hairo "*When I use MSG_NOSIGNAL flag, send returns 0*" - `send()` should never return 0, unless you request to send 0 bytes (which would be a logic bug in your code if you ever do). Otherwise, `send()` should be returning >0 on success and -1 on failure, never 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I was under the impression that the first `send` after the client had died would detect this directly but I read more about it and came up with the solution I put in my answer - which should work even in those cases where you don't have the option to `recv` to test the state.

Comment: In addition to the `EPIPE` handling, there is another problem with this code - TCP is a byte stream, so neither `send()` nor `recv()` are guaranteed to return *exactly* as many bytes as requested. This code is not handling the possibility that `send()` can return `> 0` but `< sizeof(send_msg)`, and the same for `recv()` with `sizeof(recv_msg)`. This code needs to loop the calls to `send()`/`recv()`, paying attention to the return values, to make sure all expected data is actually sent/received. `recv() has a `MSG_WAITALL` flag, but `send()` has no such flag.

Comment: @hairo Did you try my answer out?

Answer (score 0):

Any of these options should work to avoid having the `SIGPIPE` signal killing your program:

- Ignore `SIGPIPE`:

  ```
  #include <signal.h>

  int main() {
      signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
      ...
  ```
- Don't generate the `SIGPIPE` signal when `send`/`recv` tries to operate on a closed socket by supplying the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag:

  ```
  if (send(client_pool[i], send_msg, strlen(send_msg), MSG_NOSIGNAL) < 0) {
      printf("send error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  } else if (recv(client_pool[i], recv_msg, sizeof(recv_msg), MSG_NOSIGNAL) < 0) {
      printf("receive error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }
  ```

From the `send` `man` page:

`MSG_NOSIGNAL` (since Linux 2.2)

*Don't  generate a `SIGPIPE` signal if the peer on a stream-oriented socket has closed the connection. The `EPIPE` error is still returned. This provides similar behavior to using `sigaction(2)` to ignore `SIGPIPE`, but, whereas `MSG_NOSIGNAL` is a per-call feature, ignoring `SIGPIPE` sets a process attribute that affects all threads in the process.*

---

You also need to detect the state of the socket after you've used `send` since it will probably return success on the first `send` after the client has died.

You could add a helper function:

```
int checksock(int sock) { // 0 on success, -1 on failure
    int error = 0;
    socklen_t len = sizeof error;

    int rv = getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len);
    if (rv == 0 && error) {
        errno = error;     // set the thread local errno
        rv = -1;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Your sending part could then do this:

```
if (send(client_pool[i], send_msg, strlen(send_msg), MSG_NOSIGNAL) < 0
    || checksock(client_pool[i]))     // added check
{
   printf("send error: %s\n", strerror(errno));   // Broken pipe
} else if (recv(client_pool[i], recv_msg, sizeof(recv_msg), MSG_NOSIGNAL) < 0) {
   printf("receive error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: Checking `SO_ERROR` should typically only be done after a non-blocking operation ( like when `connect()` returns `EINPROGRESS`/`EWOULDBLOCK` and then `select()` reports the socket is writable ie the `connect()` operation is finished, then you use `SO_ERROR` to find out if the socket was actually connected). Otherwise, use `errno` instead, after checking return values for failure.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The difference is that since `send` returns success on the first `send` after the client has died, `errno` is `0`. Checking `SO_ERROR` with `getsockopt` on the other hand returns the error so the disconnect can be detected on first `send`.

Comment: If `send()` "succeeds", there is no guarantee that `SO_ERROR` would be updated with an error code, nor does it make sense for it to do so.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, I don't know exactly why it seems to work in practice but I read more than one recommendation to check `SO_ERROR` (and also to turn on keepalive). In my very small test I did, it never failed to detect it after first `send` but it failed to detect it constantly when just checking the return from `send`. Perhaps `getsockopt` with `SO_ERROR` is not entirely passive?